# Apache cordova var not displayed in html

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I have a problem with my application developped with angular & apache cordova on android.

On the first place I fetch the contact list from my smartphone and store it in a var : $scope.listecontacts

```
  // alert('nb contacts '+contacts.length);
             for (var i = 0; i < contacts_1.length; i++) 
             {



                    if(contacts_1[i].phoneNumbers != null && contacts_1[i].name != null && typeof contacts_1[i].phoneNumbers != 'undefined')
                    {

                               if($scope.numero_tel==0)
                              {
                                $scope.numero_tel = contacts_1[i].phoneNumbers[0].value;
                              }

                               $scope.listecontacts.push(contacts_1[i]);

                    }

                }
```

And in a second time I try to display it in the html dom like this :

```
 <div ng-repeat="t in listecontacts"   >{{(t.name.formatted)}}</div>
```

When I launch my application it runs fine but when I go back in the home page and then go on the view that fetch the contact list, the DIV is not filled with the contact list.

I have checked the variable : $scope.listecontacts and it is not empty....

Has anyone ever meet this problem ?

Have you got any Idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `$scope.listecontacts` did get destroyed, it is not retained, you need to create a service with a get method that returns the array and incorporate that service into your code.

Comment: Try and console.log() when is the view displayed, for starters we should know that when you make a query it'll take longer than the view being displayed, on top of that you have to anticipate that besides the query time you got the loop and the object.push() function.

Try to update the variables after your loop has finished…

Comment: How to update variables after the loop ? I tried this in the loop :
$scope.$apply(function () {  $scope.listecontacts.liste_1.push(contacts_1[i]);  });
But no effect :-/

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to use a service this way :

```
  app.factory('ContactService', function($window, $q, $rootScope){
                     var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                    options.filter = "";
                    options.multiple = true;
                   var filter = ["displayName", "name","phoneNumbers"];
                   // navigator.contacts.find(filter, onSuccess, onError, options);
    return {
        getContactList : function(onSuccess, onError){
            navigator.contacts.find(filter,function(contacts){
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    onSuccess(contacts);
                })
            }, function(){
                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    onError();
                })
            }, options)
        }
    }
})
```

And then in my controller :

```
$scope.get_contacts = function()
{

    /*alert('get_contacts');*/

         try
        {

         ContactService.getContactList(function(contacts)
        {
```

But nothing chages, I check the variables with the console with via USB and Chrome and the array is fileld with thje value but the HTML doesn't displays the data.

Comment: You're not calling it properly, the function `ContactService.getContactList(function(contacts)...` is incorrect, you need to call it like this `ContactService.getContactList(function gotContacts(contactList){ ... }, function errContacts(){ ... })`,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help !

Actually my service was running fine I just had to change

this :

```
  <option ng-repeat="t in listecontacts"  value="{{(t.phoneNumbers[0].value)}}" >{{(t.name.formatted)}}</option>
```

to this

```
  <option ng-repeat="t in listecontacts.liste_1"  value="{{(t.phoneNumbers[0].value)}}" >{{(t.name.formatted)}}</option>
```

since I used an object instead of an array for "listecontacts"

```
     $scope.listecontacts=   { 
    liste_1: []
  };
```